# Is it possible to remove credit card information from the google play

Tags: android

I am about to create a google play account(developer license) which cost for $25.My question is

1. **Do google stores the credit card information at time of creating
   account for google play ?**
2. **if Yes how to remove the informations ? and**
3. **Do removing the credit card info from google play has any problem
   with my developer account ?**

Comment: Why don't you ask Google?

Comment: [How to remove credit card details from google play](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=baHCUvrALs7_rAeg1oHoAg#q=how+to+remove+credit+card+details+from+google+play)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question - it is a question about google's policies.

Answer (score 2):

**Do google stores the credit card information at time of creating account for google play ?**
Yes it does. But you can skip inputting credit card information during account creation

**if Yes how to remove the informations ? and**

You may consult [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/4646404?hl=en)

> Go to your Google Play account. Select Add a payment method or Edit
>   payment method. If prompted, sign in to payments.google.com and follow
>   the on-screen instructions.
>
> Open the Google Play Store app Google Play. Touch the Menu icon Google
>   Play Store Menu Icon > My account > Add payment method or More payment
>   settings. If prompted, sign in to payments.google.com and follow the
>   on-screen instructions.

**Do removing the credit card info from google play has any problem with my developer account ?**
I do not have such account so I am not really sure. But I guess it won't be a problem. You would just have to setup again your payment method when you need to pay something (or receive payment?).

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Do google stores the credit card information at time of creating account for google play ?

Yes

> 2. if Yes how to remove the informations ? and

Go to your Google Play account.

Select Add a payment method or Edit payment method.

If prompted, sign in to payments.google.com and follow the on-screen instructions.

For more information about the payment options available when you select Add payment method (for example: carrier billing, PayPal, and Google Play credit), go to accepted payment methods.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/4646404?hl=en-IN

> 3. Do removing the credit card info from google play has any problem with my developer account ?

Yes. How do you get your In App purchase & Paid app money?

Comment: for 3rd answer. I don't want to buy any app from google play after creating my developer license once. I just only want to create developer license from my  friends credit card coz i don't have credit card. and he has little hesitation regarding this.so after creating account I want to remove that credit card information so that I can get only $25 from his credit card and after that I can continue my app to publish to the google play.

Comment: Yes, then remove it. It will not create any problem.